# Django models reference another attribute within an attribute of the same class

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to build a model for the profile details of the user of my django web app like:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(blank = True, upload_to='profile_pics/'+self.user.id+'/')
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default='India')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='NA')
    birthday = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I have an image field in the above model and I want to upload the incoming images to the path `profile_pics/<id of the user whose profile is being set up>/` within my media storage path. I tried to do that by specifying the `upload_to` attribute of the image field as `upload_to = 'profile_pics/'+self.user.id+'/'`. I am using AWS S3 for my media storage and I have put the necessary settings in my settings as:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'myaccesskeyid'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'mysecretaccesskey'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucketname'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

When I try to make the migrations, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/treeEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/treeEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/treeEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/treeEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/treeEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/treeEnv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/userMgmt/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class UserDetails(models.Model):
  File "/home/suraj/Work/treeapp/treeapp-backend/userMgmt/models.py", line 9, in UserDetails
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(blank = True, upload_to='profile_pics/'+self.user.id+'/')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Please help me out to set the default path of the image uploads to this model to `profile_pics/<id of the user whose profile is being set up>/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callable to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    def profile_picture_upload(self, filename):
        return 'profile_pics/{}/{}'.format(self.user_id, filename)

    # …
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=profile_picture_upload)
```

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `profile_picture` instead of <s>`profilePicture`</s>.